# Can membership fees be returned from the Upwork API?

Tags: upwork-api

I am a freelancer, and I have been able to use the Upwork API to get earnings information, but I can't find anywhere to pull the Membership Fee.  I noticed that 'Membership Fee' is not listed in field 'subtype' for Financial reports documented here: https://developers.upwork.com/?lang=python#reports_financial-reports-fields, so perhaps Membership Fee is not available.  I'm trying to use the API to pull a report like we can get here, with the Download CSV button:
https://www.upwork.com/nx/payments/reports/transaction-history.  I am using the Upwork Python libraries.

Any information would be much appreciated!
Thank you,
Amy Putnam

Answer (score 0):

Upwork API does not return such information.